# Search active listings by keywords on eBay

Tags: c#, ebay-api

I can't understand how should I get list of active listings (products) by keyword.

I was able to run eBay test application that returns time, but I don't know how to do a request for a product. I did some research, found examples, but they did not work.
For example:

```
FindingServicePortTypeClient client =
```

It does not work, but

```
GeteBayOfficialTimeRequestType request=
```

works fine.

I included web reference for com.ebay.developer, so the `GeteBayOfficialTimeRequestType` is present, but `GeteBayOfficialTimeRequestType` is missing.

Could anyone give me a working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use the eBay finding API; they actually have different API's and I used the wrong one